# How do I fix this error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Tags: swift

I want to make a space invaders game on Xcode and I get an error in the GameViewController.swift file saying:

Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

I am new at this and want to learn swift to develop games that can be download from the app store.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene (scene)
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the test run I expected a window to pop up and show my ship and background but it says "Build Failed" and shows my error and I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: On what line are you getting the error message?

Comment: There are invisible characters after the last closing bracket. Just delete and retype that line.

Comment: Unrelated but please indent your code properly. It will be so much easier to read by you and anyone else viewing your code.